# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null - Node Canvas

Tags: node.js, canvas

I have tried running my Nodejs script project in Linux which is working just fine but whenever I try running the same project in Windows, it is throwing an error. I have been trying to resolve this issue since last few days. Not sure why I am getting this problem. Please help me guys to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

```
xyz\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:61
        fn = function () { throw arg; };
                           ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
at Object.acquireContext (E:\app_server\node_modules\chart.js\src\platforms\platform.dom.js:340:19)
at Chart.construct (E:app_server\node_modules\chart.js\src\core\core.controller.js:79:27)
at new Chart (E:\app_server\node_modules\chart.js\src\core\core.js:42:8)
at jsdom.envAsync.then.window (E:\app_server\node_modules\chartjs-node\index.js:106:31)
at tryCatcher (E:\app_server\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (E:\app_server\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
at Promise._settlePromise (E:\app_server\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
at Promise._settlePromise0 (E:\app_server\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
at Promise._settlePromises (E:\app_server\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:693:18)
at Promise._fulfill (E:\app_server\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:638:18)
at Object.done (E:\app_server\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\nodeback.js:42:21)
at process.nextTick (E:\app_server\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom.js:320:18)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I got its look like you are using above canvas-2.0.0 alpha.8 library and it is in an alpha testing phase some of the people got the same issue had you got and I got. I refer from this GitHub open issue https://github.com/vmpowerio/chartjs-node/issues/42 .I had also the same issue regarding the canvas-2.0.0 alpha.13 and I am downgrade canvas 2.0.0-alpha.2 and it worked for me. Try to install below command
npm i canvas@2.0.0-alpha.2

Answer (score 0):

this error probably not caused by the 'bluebird',I think it is because you access the 'length' property of a variable and the variable is null;

can you add the whole error tips? sorry my reputation is not enough to add a comment;

Comment: why is this an answer hu, just add this in comment.

Comment: comment needs 50 reputation... :(

Comment: My bad captain.

Comment: but my script proper run in ubuntu  but it could not be run in windows

Comment: can you add the whole error message in your question description? platform errors can be caused by lots of reasons;

Comment: at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)

Comment: check these two places, you can also add ```debugger``` there,then enter ```F12``` in browser to call ```chrome or firefox DEV tool```;the steps in the answer above is detailed; refresh the program and it will stop there(```debugger```place); and then maybe you can see something like ```something.length ``` ,and the value of   ``` something```  is  ```null```,you can find a tool named ```call stack```  on the rigth or bottom part of the ```DEV tool``` show details.

Comment: sorry but it's not a web-based application I am using it as console-based for simply using that for generating a graph using canvas.

Comment: ```internal/process/next_tick.js:  line: 131    internal/process/next_tick.js line: 180 ``` are these two place has something like ```something.length```? if you use an ide, you can find ```debug ***.js``` under menu item [run] and you can add some breakpoints;

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Open Dev Tools in Google Chrome (there are similar tools in other browsers).
2. Open the "Sources" tab.
3. Click on the "Pause on exceptions" button, which looks like a pause symbol inside an octagon, on the top right corner of the tab.
4. Check the "Pause on caught exceptions" checkbox.
5. Recreate the flow that lead to the error while the Dev Tools window is still open.

The code will brake on the error. If the brake will be on a code that is part of `bluebird` or anything else that you didn't write, go up the stack trace until you hit a line that was written by you. See what is happening in this line and it should be quite simple to understand what went wrong.

Comment: sorry but it's not a web-based application I am using it as console-based for simply using that for generating a graph using canvas.